# Apache camel Tests fails with : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'null' - retrying in 5000ms. cause: null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, apache-camel, activemq-classic

i have this really annoying problem where i have developed and tested an Apache Camel  module for larger application, everything was looking great until i committed my code to the main repository and Jenkins tried build and run my tests.

Locally (on my windows machine) maven builds and runs everything fine however on our jenkins server (linux) it fails every single test with the error.

```
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'null' - retrying in 5000ms. cause: null
```

The application is fairly simple, it accepts messages from one queue, then does some validation and transformation and send it out on another queue.

On my machine all mocked endpoints can be asserted with expected values while on our jenkins server these mocked endpoint assertions get timed-out after 10 seconds. this is not a work load issue as the test data is processed in milliseconds on my machine. i can also see that everything that i expect to happen happens in our logs.

The application is built on Spring 3.2.14, it uses Apache Camel 2.15.2 and for testing purposes i'm using ActiveMQ 5.11.1. i have made sure that there is only one version of each framework so there shouldn't be any conflicts 
(checked it with mvn dependency:tree)

I am most likely not permitted to show any of code so for now i'll make this post without it.

Any suggestion to what might be the cause is much appreciated.

EDIT1:

here's the camel routes (simplified):

```
// camel route A  : entry point
@Inject
private Queue queueInn;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
from("jms:queue:" + queueInn.getName()))
    .routeId(ROUTE_NAME)
    .multicast()
        // TODO add additional routes add them to the parameter list to(queueA, queueB, .....)
    .to(QueueA.IN_QUEUE)
.end();
}

// camel route B: basic logic
@Override public void configure() throws Exception {

from(IN_QUEUE)
    .routeId(ROUTE_NAME)
    .process(new MDCContextProcessor())

        //Error handling
    .onException(Throwable.class)
        .setBody(exchangeProperty(CommonProperties.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE))
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, LOG, "... \n${exception.message} \n${exception.stacktrace}")
        .to(QueueUtil.getCamelQueue(errorQueue))
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, LOG, "...")
        .stop()
    .end()

        // processing
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOG, "...")
    .setProperty(CommonProperties.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE, body())
     .to("validator:" + XSD_A)
    .unmarshal(jaxbFormatA)

    .choice()
        .when(predicateA)
        .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOG, "...")
        .process(mapperA)
        .marshal(jaxbFormatB)
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("validator:" + XSD_B)
        .to("jms:queue:" + queueOut.getName())
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOG, "...")
    .otherwise()
        .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOG, "...")
    .endChoice();
```

}

UPDATE 2:

After a lot of debugging and testing we have concluded that our problem is related to our Camel test context, when no other tests are ran expect  our camel tests they run fine, however if we have other Spring tests that use the same config as our Camel tests, mocked endpoints start behaving strangely. this is however only the case when our normal Spring tests are executed before our camel tests. if our camel tests are the first to run, they work just fine. this is the difference between our local  build and our CI server and the cause of our problem.

UPDATE 3:
I now have a temporarily workaround for my problem, i use @DirtiesContext on all other tests that uses my test context. While this works, i would prefer to be able to tell my camel test class that it needs create a new fresh context before it starts running its tests, anyone know how i might do this?

Comment: Can you post your camel route?

Comment: Stupid question, do you have ActiveMQ running locally, but not on Jenkins?

Comment: The tests i've written use a TestConfiguration that starts a ActiveMQ broker and shuts it down after runing the tests, the log also show that it has been started and that it gets messages. As for posting the route, ill have to get back to work, so i might be able to post it in 2-3 hours.

Comment: After some debugging on both server an locally i have come to the conclusion that for some reason surefire running on Jenkins is making the tests create multiple Camel context instances while this does not seem to happen locally. I have gotten some feedback suggesting that it could be a problem with the mocking and assertion of endpoints in camel but I’m not sure what to make out of it. 

i am using 
      @MockEndpoints
       ...
     @EndpointInject(uri = "uriHere")
     public MockEndpoint mock